# Update existing asp.net Project with WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have eCommerce ASP.net Project, This project have 20 important dlls and more java script files when i want to update website for my clients i have to give them dlls and js files and ask them to replace new files with old files and many many troubles.

---

But I want to create system like web service to update each client automatically like antivirus Update !

**Is That even possible  !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191532.aspx)?

It's a microsoft tool that allows you to update the client automatically. When the client opens the application, it asks the server if there are any updates - If there are, it downloads them and updates. If not - nothing special happens and the app just start regulary.

Answer (score 1):

A [Web Deploy Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx) works quite nicely.

**Create Package:**
right click `Publish` and choose `Web Deploy Package`. This creates a `.zip` deploy package, which you can then easily import into IIS.

**Deploy to IIS 7:**
right click your site -> `Deploy` -> `Import Application` -> Navigate to the .zip deployment package, that's it. [Here's a detailed walkthrough](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/manually-installing-web-packages)